# setting kerning for a glyph and a ligature

Tags: ligatures, kerning, font-metrics

How can one specify in PL-file the kerning for a glyph and a ligature (say, digit and en-dash) except for setting it for the first part of the ligature (which I would like to avoid)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have separate kerning for `0`/hyphen and `0`/en-dash unless you input the en-dash directly as `\char...` (masked by a macro, of course).

Comment: @egreg Are you sure? The reason I ask is that if you construct a ligature from existing glyphs, you copy the kerning from the originals to ensure correct kerning on each side. So if I'm constructing `fi`, I'd copy the left kerning pairs from `f` and the right kerning pairs from `i`. If it wasn't possible for the kerning to be different, there couldn't be any need to do this, could there? For example, `latin.mtx` includes `\setleftkerning{ffi}{f}{1000}` and `\setrightkerning{ffi}{i}{1000}` to get the kerning of `ffi` with other characters right.

Comment: Why is this tagged `dvips`, by the way? It is in no way specific to that but is relevant to all cases where standard TeX fonts are used, including pdfTeX etc.

Comment: I tried adding `(LABEL C 0)(KRN O 174 R 2)(STOP)` to the ligatures of `cmr12`; then `0-`, `0--` and `0---` show no kerning; if I change `174` in `55`, the kern is added to all three instances. Note: I used `cmr12` because `cmr10` is preloaded, so a new TFM is not read in.

Comment: The situation about kerning *after* a ligature is different: when TeX examines a word for inserting kerning, it looks at character pairs *before* doing ligatures; so `0-` and `0--` are the same as far as the kerning after `0` is concerned; but `ff'` is different: `ff` has already been transformed into a ligature (octal 13), so a kern between octal 13 and `'` must exist. At least this is how I read the rules.

Comment: Which version of latex are you using: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX? If it's LuaLaTeX and if you're using an OpenType font, you could achieve your objective by setting up a so-called feature file that contains the extra kerning information

Comment: @egreg So `\setleftkerning{ffi}{f}{1000}` is, in fact, pointless because that kerning would be applied anyway?

Comment: @Mico Since the question asks about PL files, it seems safe to assume that the OP is not using an opentype font ;).

Comment: @cfr Not really; one might input `ffi` directly (well, this is not very likely). For the “digit/en-dash” problem one can arrange that directly inputting `–` calls `\char'173` (which is basically what `inputenc` does).

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Oh, well. I think my brain has disappeared. I can't even now figure out why `55` and `174` even though I certainly *should*.

Comment: @cfr I always have to look at the font table to find the numbers.

Comment: @egreg Where? That is, I know where to find tables for font encodings and I know how those relate to other fonts but I don't know for the base TeX fonts. (So in the `.afm, character 55 is 7 and character 174 is ff.)

Comment: @cfr The TeXbook, of course; `cmr10` is on page 427. But also `pdflatex nfssfont` can be handy: you interactively set the font you want the table of. Type `cmr10` at the first prompt and `\table\bye` at the second one. The commands are the same as described in the METAFONTbook for `testfont.tex`, but with `nfssfont` you can also call a font by LaTeX attributes: just hit return at the first prompt instead of supplying a TFM name and you'll be presented with questions for encoding, family, weight, shape and size.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I should probably... er... look at the TeXbook at some time. (I did once to try to figure out how TeX typeset maths and have never dared return.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experiment, described below, seems to prove that this is impossible. When TeX finds the cluster of characters

```
abc
```

(where `abc` represents any three characters) it looks whether a kerning pair or ligature for `ab` is defined and, in this case it inserts the kern or makes the ligature. If the ligaturing mechanism has substituted `d` to `ab`, a kern or ligature between `d` and `c` is tried; otherwise the pair `bc` is considered.

Here's the description of the experiment.

1. I converted `cmr12.tfm` to `cmr12.pl` with `tftopl`.
2. I added the lines

   ```
   (LABEL C 0)
   (KRN O 174 R 2)
   (STOP)
   ```

   to the `LIGTABLE` property, which should define a kerning pair between `0` and the em-dash and ran `pltotf`.
3. I ran TeX on the test file

   ```
   \font\x=cmr12 \x % load the modified font metric file
   0-\par
   0--\par
   0---\par
   \bye
   ```

   and no kern showed up.
4. I changed the lines above in the `cmr12.pl` file into

   ```
   (LABEL C 0)
   (KRN O 55 R 2)
   (STOP)
   ```

   (octal 55 is the slot for the hyphen), converted again to a `.tfm` file and ran again TeX on the test file above; in this case the kern showed up on all three lines.

The situation *after* a ligature is different and, indeed, `cmr12.pl` shows the same kerning pairs for `f` and octal 13 (ligature `ff`), to wit

```
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C i O 14)
   (LIG C f O 13)
   (LIG C l O 15)
   (KRN O 47 R 0.069734)
   (KRN O 77 R 0.069734)
   (KRN O 41 R 0.069734)
   (KRN O 51 R 0.069734)
   (KRN O 135 R 0.069734)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 13)
   (LIG C i O 16)
   (LIG C l O 17)
   (KRN O 47 R 0.069734)
   (KRN O 77 R 0.069734)
   (KRN O 41 R 0.069734)
   (KRN O 51 R 0.069734)
   (KRN O 135 R 0.069734)
   (STOP)
```

which confirms my preliminary analysis.

Of course a kerning pair between 0 and the en-dash *can* be specified, but it will come into action only if

```
0\char'173
```

is input (maybe via direct input of the en-dash with a mechanism similar to what `inputenc` does for LaTeX).